# Error 500 when trying to access IBM Watson Assistant Message through Axios (React Natve)

Tags: react-native, axios, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

[image: This is the error I get]

This is the error I get when I try to retrieve data from IBM Watson Assistant using this code, I am in a React Native environment using axios to request and respond:

```
//ASSISTANT GREETING
init = async session => {
    try 
    {
        const _backendEndpoint = 'https://MYAPPLICATIONNAME.mybluemix.net';
        const initialPayload = {
            input: {
                message_type: 'text',
                text: '',
            },
        };

        let response = await axios.post(`${_backendEndpoint}/api/message`, {
            ...initialPayload,
            ...session,
        });

        this.setState({ userSession: session });
        this.setState({ text: response.data.output.generic[0].text });
        this.setState({ userPayload: response.data });
    } 

    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to retrive data from Watson API', err);
    }
};
```

Did IBM Change their codebase or something so you can no longer get requests? I am at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: There have been changes, but these shouldn't affect applications that were currently working. Was this working before? Can you paste the 500 error that you get? API reference: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node

Comment: @drnugent Thank you for the response! This was not working before, it is a completely new app :/ and I'm not quite sure how to get the exact 500 error, but it seems to be unable to fetch anything from the bluemix URL. Sorry, I'm new to this!

Comment: What is the mybluemix.net URI? Is that your app and you built an API to retrieve from? The Watson Assistant APIs have different endpoints.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be improved by restating it in the following format: "I am trying to accomplish X. I am using code from the tutorial/documentation at A, B, C. It is giving me this detailed error message." If you show us what you are working off of and what you are trying to accomplish, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting `https://MYAPPLICATIONNAME.mybluemix.net` to be your instance of Watson Assistant then this is not going to work. The endpoint should look something like `https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com`

see the API documentation for a list of endpoints for the regions- https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=python#service-endpoint

The endpoint that you use will depend on which region you have your Watson Assistant.

You also need to authenticate with the server, which isn't apparent in your code snippet.

If, however, `https://MYAPPLICATIONNAME.mybluemix.net` is your backend application server, then I expect it should have an API endpoint defined for `/api/message`, where your error is occurring. Please share the code for your `/api/message` endpoint. If you don't have any, then that is why you are getting a 500 error.